# How can I "print" text in Javascript while pausing the script

Tags: javascript, wait, sleep

I want to "print" / "echo" text in javascript while pausing the script between.
Currently my script works but it prints all at the same time .

Sorry I am not familiar with Javascript

```
<script>
function wait(ms)
{
    var d = new Date();
    var d2 = null;
    do { d2 = new Date(); }
    while(d2-d < ms);
}
wait(1000);
document.write('hello');
wait(1000);
document.write(' how are you?');
</script>
```

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to run code periodically.

Comment: Use an array and a function: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vk4sd2t7/

Comment: this works https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vk4sd2t7/
but is this only for plain text or I can add html or iframe ?